# Dividing each column by previous column in R

Tags: r

I have the following data frame:

```
df <- data.frame(type = c("planes", "trains", "automobiles"), t1 = c(4, 5, 6), t2 = c(20, 60, 24), t3 = c(100, 120, 72), t4 = c(800, 360, 144))

 df
         type t1 t2  t3  t4
1      planes  4 20 100 800
2      trains  5 60 120 360
3 automobiles  6 24  72 144
```

I'd like to write a function that takes the values in each column and divides them by the prior column, starting with t2 / t1, so that I get a new data frame that looks like this:

```
new_df
         type t1 t2 t3 t4
1      planes     5  5  8
2      trains    12  2  3
3 automobiles     4  3  2
```

There may be a way to do this with the sweep function, but I haven't been able to find it yet.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `df[,3:5]/df[2:4]` is okay?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
df[, 3:5] <- df[, 3:5] / df[, 2:4]

#          type t1 t2 t3 t4
# 1      planes  4  5  5  8
# 2      trains  5 12  2  3
# 3 automobiles  6  4  3  2
```

`Map` would also work

```
df[, 3:5] <- Map('/', df[, 3:5], df[, 2:4])

#          type t1 t2 t3 t4
# 1      planes  4  5  5  8
# 2      trains  5 12  2  3
# 3 automobiles  6  4  3  2
```

Comment: @DavidArenburg No coercion to matrix might be a plus. On the other hand, `/` needs to be applied three times with `Map`.

Comment: @Frank maybe I'm missing something, but what is exactly coerced to a matrix? `class(df[, 3:5]/df[, 2:4])` seems to be a `data.frame` class

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps more generically:

```
func <- function(x) {
    numcols <- ! sapply(x, class) %in% c('character','factor')
    nc <- sum(numcols)
    if (nc > 1) {
        m <- x[,numcols]
        x[,numcols] <- m[,2:nc] / m[,1:(nc-1)]
    }
    x
}
func(df)
##          type t1 t2 t3 t4
## 1      planes  5  5  8  5
## 2      trains 12  2  3 12
## 3 automobiles  4  3  2  4
```

You'll likely want to add safeguards for zeroes in the denominator, dividing by `FALSE` (same thing), and other such corner-cases.