# How to operate on columns based on column position systematically?

Tags: r

Is there a way to systematically divide columns based on position of the column?
For example, with a data frame like this:

```
df <- data.frame(id = ('a1', 'a2'), a = c(1, 0), b = c(4,0), c = c(4, 3), d = c(5, 10))
```

| a | b | c | d |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 4 | 4 | 5 |
| 0 | 0 | 3 | 10 |

I want to get:

| a | b | c | d | div_c | div_b | div_a |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 4 | 4 | 5 | 0.8 | 1 | 0.25 |
| 0 | 0 | 3 | 10 | 0.3 | 0 | NaN |

In other words, starting at the last column as the numerator and the column previous as the numerator until the first column is the numerator.
which, I know I can get this by:

```
df %>% mutate(div_c = c/d, div_b = b/c, div_a = a/b)
```

However, I have many more columns than the example above, so I would like to know if there is a better way to do this than typing every new calculation.

I tried mutate and across, but that only works if the operation/function is consistent across instead of a moving target.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do

```
> cbind(df, div=(df[-c(1, ncol(df))]/df[-(1:2)])[, rev(seq_len(ncol(df) - 2L))])
  id a b c  d div.c div.b div.a
1 a1 1 4 4  5   0.8     1  0.25
2 a2 0 0 3 10   0.3     0   NaN
```

---

*Data:*

```
> dput(df)
structure(list(id = c("a1", "a2"), a = c(1, 0), b = c(4, 0), 
    c = c(4, 3), d = c(5, 10)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-2L))
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is modified version of a solution discovered years ago [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30493258/dividing-each-column-by-previous-column-in-r) provided by @r2evans:

#### base R

```
func <- function(x) {
  numcols <- ! sapply(x, class) %in% c('character','factor')
  nc <- sum(numcols)
  if (nc > 1) {
    m <- x[,numcols]
    x[,numcols] <- m[,1:(nc-1)]/m[,2:nc] 
  }
  x
}

func(df[,-1]) |>
  set_names(paste0("div_", colnames(df[,-1]))) |>
  cbind(df)
```

#### tidyverse

```
  library(dplyr)
  library(purrr)
  
  func <- function(df) {
    numeric_df <- df[-1]
    div_df <- map2_dfc(numeric_df[-ncol(numeric_df)], 
                       numeric_df[-1], 
                       ~ .x / .y) %>% 
      setNames(paste0("div_", names(numeric_df)[-ncol(numeric_df)]))
    bind_cols(df[1], div_df, numeric_df)
  }
  

  func(df)

  id div_a div_b div_c a b c  d
1 a1  0.25     1   0.8 1 4 4  5
2 a2   NaN     0   0.3 0 0 3 10
```